# Select multiple coulmns with linq method syntax

Tags: linq-to-sql

How do I select multiple columns in linq to sql method syntax? I only know how to select one column but not multiple columns.

Like if I had a this table

```
ProductId
ProductName
ProductQty
ProductNumber
```

How could I select productName and ProductQty but not ProductNumber or ProductId in linq to sql method syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

something like this:

```
from item in db.products
select new {item.ProductName, item.ProductQty};
```

or

```
db.products.Select( item => new {item.ProductName, item.ProductQty} );
```